# ¿como hacer que un programa en python arranque desde el inicio del SO de la raspberry?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

hice un programa en python en una raspberry pi, ui en tkinter, funciona perfecto ahora quiero que cada vez que arranque el sistema operativo solo arranque esa aplicacion. Còmo hago esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de probar todo lo que encontre en internet esta fue la que me funcionò exactamente como queria, modificando el archivo autostart y estos son los pasos

```
cd /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

sudo nano autotart
```

y al final escribir

```
sudo python /RUTA/script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Edita el archivo `/etc/rc.local` y añade ahí la llamada al script.

1. Edita `rc.local`: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
2. Añade la llamada al script donde quieras que vaya (siempre antes de `exit 0`): `sudo python /ruta/al/script.py`
3. Si tu programa tiene un bucle infinito o no va a terminar, deberás añadir un `&` para no bloquear el inicio del sistema operativo. En ese caso el paso anterior sería: `sudo python /ruta/al/script.py &`.

El script se ejecutará antes que otros servicios, no sé si te vale eso, o necesitas tener el sistema ya preparado.

Otra opción similar es lo mismo de arriba, pero en el archivo `.bashrc` (en la ruta de tu usuario, probablemente `/home/pi/.bashrc`). En este caso el script se ejecutaría tanto al inicio del sistema operativo, como cada vez que abras una terminal, así que quizá no te valga.

Otra opción es añadirlo a la carpeta `init.d`, pero es más compleja. Puedes buscar detalles en internet si lo necesitas.

Y otra opción es usar `crontab`, también busca en internet qué es e investiga un poco y encontrarás cómo ejecutar el script al encender la Raspberry Pi

Comment: que significa el "al" en :sudo python /ruta/al/script.py &

Comment: He probado con estas 5 formas: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/ y ninguna funciona. algun comentario?

Comment: Donde dice `/ruta/al/script.py` quería decir que cambies eso por la ruta al script, ya que no sé dónde lo guardas, eso lo sabrás tú. A eso me refería. Si ninguna de las opciones de esa página te funciona, ya no sé qué puede ser. ¿Puede que tu script no esté funcionando bien?

Comment: es decir te equivocaste y quisiste escribir /ruta/script.py

Comment: No. Puse lo que quería poner. En inglés pondría `/path/to/script.py`, en castellano puse `/ruta/al/script.py`. No hay más misterio, quizá te lió eso un poco, lo siento. Me alegro de que lo tengas solucionado.

Comment: entiendo: "al" es "to" . caso cerrado, gracias por responder.